# For Loop Card game stuck

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I am trying to design a card game in java that scores 1 point for each card in a run of 3 or more consecutive cards in a hand of 5 cards (does not have to be the same suit). Example 2,3,K,3,4 = 2 runs (2,3,4 & 2,3,4)-(swapping the 3)

However I'm stuck on how should I write this code.. can someone guide me to the right direction?

This is what I have so far:

```
public static int[] card; 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] card = new int[5];

    for (card1 = 0; card1 <= 4; card1++) {
        if (card[1] == card[0] + 1) {
            for (card2 = card1 + 1; card2 <= 4; card2++) {
                if (card[2] == card[1] + 1) {
                    countvalueforRun++;
                }

                for (card3 = card2 + 1; card3 <= 4; card3++) {
                    if (card[3] == card[2] + 1) {
                        countvalueforRun++;
                    }

                    for (card4 = card3 + 1; card4 <= 4; card4++) {
                        if (card[3] == card[3] + 1) {
                            countvalueforRun++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println((countvalueforRun));
}
```

Comment: You are asking logic? I think you should try it by own.

Comment: How many runs should `2,3,4,5,6` count as? In your example you allow the cards to be reused for multiple points, so should this score 6 points, i.e., `2,3,4`, `3,4,5`, `4,5,6`, `2,3,4,5`, `3,4,5,6`, `2,3,4,5,6`? If so, the logic seems quite convoluted…

Comment: Try to start from simple version. For example two card with same value score 1

Comment: @DeepakTiwari The problem is im stuck on logic :(

Comment: You should really think this through and decide what you want to do step by step, this looks like a mess. Not to mention, lines like `card[3] == card[3] + 1` will ALWAYS be false.

Comment: you never define/initialize `countvalueforRun` in your code. Also, you define `cards[]` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking the direction only here it is:

Assuming that you have devised a method for Card input like user entry or Random, i would approach the problem as follows:

Step1: First would arrange the arrange in ascending order by initializing another array cardArranged[card.length] by using nested for & if loop.

Step2: Run the cardArranged in 2 nested for loops, checking each card whether it has a "Run" in the pack or not. Also the moment a sequence crosses (count of) 3, your countvalueforRun gives +1.

```
for(int i=0;i<cardArranged.length;i++)
    {
    int sequence = 0; 
    int cardCount=0;
    for(int j=i;j<cardArranged.length;j++) //j=i because cards are arranged in ascending order
    {
     if(cardArranged[i]==cardArranged[cardCount]+1)
      { 
       sequence++;
      } 
     cardCount++;
     }

     if(sequence>=3)
     {
       countvalueforRun++;
      }
```

Step 3: Print countvalueforRun

Hope that helps !!